# JupyterLab kernel dies when plotting 100k markers in folium

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, jupyter-lab, folium

I am trying to add popups in the map. Size of the dataframe that I am using here is 135800 rows x 6 columns

```
for lat, lng, city in zip(df_address['lat'], df_address['lon'], df_address['admin2']):
    label = '{}'.format(city)
    label = folium.Popup(label, parse_html=True)   # create a popup
    folium.CircleMarker(
        [lat, lng], radius=5, popup=label, color='blue', fill=True,
        fill_color='#3186cc', fill_opacity=0.7, parse_html=True).add_to(map_saopaulo)
```

After it iterates over the for loop for a while, it seemingly creates map then it crashes right after.

Is there a way to solve this problem or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did your program worked for small data?

Comment: I haven't tried in this specific project but I've tried in the previous one and it worked with small data.

Comment: can you post if there is any exception or error and also add your system specifications

Comment: There was no exception or error. I tried to run it three times and I could see the map returned once but then it starts to lag so bad then Jupyter get crashed few seconds after. And system specifications of what did u mean?

Comment: what processor are you using how much ram etc.

Comment: I got 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5 and Memory is 8GB 1600 MHz DDR3. I am actually thinking of getting a new laptop..haha.. it's getting outdated.

Comment: try running it on [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)

Comment: Try it outside jupyter, and it will have a bit better chance of working. Still 135000 markers is quite a lot.

Comment: Yeah, thats a lot of markers.  Have a look at folium's MarkerClusters and FastMarkerClusters

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I tried using Colab but I couldn't even start since I kept getting an [Errno 2] error for importing the dataset. I tried everything I could but couldn't fix the problem.

Comment: FastMarkerCluters worked for me. Thank you so much. I think I should not use popups since there are too many and it crashes the program.